# Constant functions in set-theory

Tags: set-theory

I need some help with an exercise in set theory, which is about certain constant functions.

Let $S$ be a stationary subset of a regular uncountable cardinal $\lambda$. Given an ordinal $\alpha$, let $c_\alpha^\lambda$ denote the constant function with domain $\lambda$ and range $\{\alpha\}$.

Letting $\psi,\varphi$ range over all ordinal-valued functions with domain $\lambda$, define $$\varphi<_S\psi\mbox{ if and only if }\{\delta\in S\mid \varphi(\delta)≥\psi(\delta)\}\mbox{ is non-stationary}.$$ The relation $<_S$ is well-founded, so we can use it to define a rank $\|\cdot\|_S$ by recursion as
$$ \|\psi\|_S=\bigcup\{\|\varphi\|_S+1\mid \varphi<_S\psi\}. $$

> How can we prove that, for all $\alpha\in{\rm Ord}$, $\|c_\alpha^\lambda\|_S \ge\alpha$ holds?
>
> How can we determine the value of $\|c_\alpha^\lambda\|_S$ for all $\alpha<\lambda$?
>
> Can we prove that $\|c_\lambda^\lambda\|_S >\lambda$?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: You might want to provide a definition of $\|f\|_S$ as well.

Comment: What precisely is difficult here?

Comment: $||Ψ||_S= \bigcup\ \{ ||φ||_S +1 | φ<_S Ψ\}$ is the definition of the S-rank, with S being stationary and $φ<_S ψ $ iff $ \{δ∈S|φ(δ)> ψ(δ)\} ∈ NS_λ$ (NS is the Non-stationary ideal on λ).   I just can't seem to figure out how I can determine the rank of the constant function, and thus don't know how to prove anything about it.

Comment: Do you see that $\|c_\alpha^\lambda\|_S$ is an ordinal for all $\alpha$, and can you prove that $\|c_\alpha^\lambda\|_S>\|c_\beta^\lambda\|_S$ whenever $\alpha>\beta$?

Comment: @Andrés E. Caicedo  I understand that $||c_α^λ||_S$ is an ordinal, but I do not know how to prove that $||c_α^λ||_S > ||c_β^λ||_S$ for α>β

Comment: Do you understand why $<_S$ is well-founded?

Comment: Yes, I proved it already via contradiction and using AC

Comment: Well, then use the definition to show that $\|c_\alpha^\lambda\|_S>\|c_\beta^\lambda\|_S$ whenever $\alpha>\beta$. It should be trivial.

Comment: Ok, I proved it...but I still don't know how I can use this to solve the problem

Comment: In your question, are you sure the last $\ge$ is not actually meant to be $>$? That is, shouldn't the last part of your question be asking to check whether $\|c_\lambda^\lambda\|_S>\lambda$?

Comment: Oh, yes indeed. Thank you, I made that small typo...

Comment: In your definition of $<_S$, are you sure you did not mean $\{\delta\in S\mid \varphi(\delta)\ge\psi(\delta)\}$ is non-stationary?, i.e., with $\ge$ instead of $>$?

Comment: Can you prove that if $\alpha<\beta$ then $c_\alpha^\lambda <_S c_\beta^\lambda$? Then the main claim would follow by a dead-simple induction on $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\alpha\mapsto\|c_\alpha^\lambda\|_S$ is strictly increasing (trivially): After all, $$\{\delta\in S\mid c_\beta^\lambda(\delta)\ge c_\alpha^\lambda(\delta)\}=\{\delta\in S\mid\beta\ge \alpha\}=\emptyset$$ if $\beta<\alpha$. This immediately gives that $\|c_\alpha^\lambda\|_S\ge\alpha$ for all $\alpha$.

Suppose now that $f<c_\alpha^\lambda$. This means that $\{\delta\in S\mid f(\delta)\ge \alpha\}$ is non-stationary, or, what is the same, $f(\delta)<\alpha$ for almost every $\delta\in S$. If, in addition, $\alpha<\lambda$, then in fact $f(\delta)<\delta$ for almost every $\delta\in S$. Use Fodor's lemma to conclude that $f$ coincides with some $c_\beta^\lambda$ for some $\beta<\alpha$ ("coincides" in the sense of $=_S$, where $f=_S g$ implies in particular that $\|f\|_S=\|g\|_S$). This should give you that $\|c_\alpha^\lambda\|_S=\alpha$ for all $\alpha<\lambda$.

Finally, check that the identity map is above all $c_\alpha^\lambda$, $\alpha<\lambda$, and below $c_\lambda^\lambda$.

Comment: Thank you very much!   Just one more question: Why is the identity map below $c_λ^λ$? I don't understand this point

Comment: Use the definitions, it is just as immediate as the other properties we discussed in the comments above.